# Telegram bot Doesnt work on certain groups

Tags: message, bots, send, telegram

I'm here to ask for help. I tried to look into it myself but I ran out of ideas. I have this Telegram Bot that is inside 8 groups each one of 100 members and it collects certain words and put them in a db. When someone use a certain command the bot replies with all the words he collected (there's also advanced search and a lot of things but not relevant at the moment). All worked fine for a month until yesterday when someone tried to see all the words using the command and the bot didnt reply. He also stopped to collect words (something he was doing without an input, he just check every message). Tried it in private and it worked , tried in another group of 2 people (me and the bot) and all worked fine. So I tried to execute this in my browser

`https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?disable_web_page_preview=false&chat_id={chatid}&text=TEST`

and it worked on all groups i've sent that. After that message all started to work fine again in every group I've done it. Now the same prob arises after few hours and only in these groups full of people. If someone has an Idea about the problem I would be happy to hear and try it out. Thanks and sorry for my mistakes , english is not my main language.

Comment: Well I solved the problem , not really solved but worked around it. in those chat suddently commands starting with "/" didnt work anymore. Changing commads worked fine. Doesn't make any sense... at least for me